# UITableview with NSArray contains NSDictionary and NSDictionary containg another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsdictionary

This is the response from Server side i am getting.
matches is dictionary .
i am using value for key but not helping me.

```
       {
    0 =     {

    "shop_name" = sujeet;
    subcategory =         {
        0 =             {
            subcategory = "Hair cut";
            "subcategory_id" = 16;
        };
    };
};
1 =     {

    "shop_name" = "Scissors Men's Parlour";
    subcategory =         {
        0 =             {
            subcategory = "Children Hair Cut";
            "subcategory_id" = 19;
        };
    };
};
2 =     {

    "shop_name" = "Mirror Beauty Parlour";
    subcategory =         {
        0 =             {
            subcategory = "Beauty parlour";
            "subcategory_id" = 14;
        };
        1 =             {
            subcategory = Manicure;
            "subcategory_id" = 25;
        };
        10 =             {
            subcategory = "Wax Half Legs";
            "subcategory_id" = 34;
        };
        11 =             {
            subcategory = "Eyebrow Tint";
            "subcategory_id" = 36;
        };
        2 =             {
            subcategory = Pedicure;
            "subcategory_id" = 26;
        };
        3 =             {
            subcategory = "Facial Massage";
            "subcategory_id" = 27;

        };
    };
};
3 =     {

    "shop_name" = "Sheela's beauty salon";
    subcategory =         {
        0 =             {
            subcategory = "Children Hair Cut";
            "subcategory_id" = 19;
        };

    };
};
};
}
```

i want to put subcategory and shop_name on uitableview cell 
my code 
first i am trying to know how many dictionary count i am getting

```
     myCount = [MAtches count];
           NSString *inStr;
            for (i = 0; i < myCount; i++)
            {
                inStr = [@(i) stringValue];
                [connt addObject:inStr];

            }

doing this 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
{
    cell.Shop_Name.text=[MAtches valueForKey:[connt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: does any one know how to print that value

Comment: your json formate difficult because your in data extra key like 0=, 1= something it remove from json not need it. @user3189586

Comment: is there something exist to remove those 0=,1=

Comment: i am facing too much difficulty

Comment: your json formate is wrong please check it. and correct formate like this way 
  `[
   {
       "shop_name" : "sujeet",
       "subcategory" :[{
            "subcategory" : "Hair cut",
            "subcategory_id" : 16,
        }
    ]
},
{
    "shop_name": "Scissors Men's Parlour",
    "subcategory" :[{
            "subcategory" : "Children Hair Cut",
            "subcategory_id" : 19,
        }
    ]
}
]`

Comment: this is the response from web service in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to get value from your json response

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict= yourdata store in dictionary;

    for (int i=0; i<[dict allKeys].count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]);// return first array object means 0 key value
        NSLog(@"%@",[[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]] objectForKey:@"shop_name"]);// return shop name

    }
```

use this way in your table delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.Shop_Name.text=[[yourJsonDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] objectForKey:@"shop_name"]; // print shop name 
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourJsonDictionary allKeys].count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an irregular keys try this, i tried and used the `NSDictionary` : `2` to make this example.. ;) Cheers.

```
NSDictionary *tempDic = @{
    @"shop_name" : @"Mirror Beauty Parlour",
    @"subcategory":
       @{
           @0: @{
                   @"subcategory": @"Beauty parlour",
                   @"subcategory_id": @14
                },
           @1: @{
                   @"subcategory": @"Manicure",
                   @"subcategory_id": @25
               },
           @10:@{
                   @"subcategory": @"Wax Half Legs",
                   @"subcategory_id": @35
               },
           @11:@{
                   @"subcategory": @"Eyebrow Tint",
                   @"subcategory_id": @36
               },
           @2: @{
                   @"subcategory": @"Pedicure",
                   @"subcategory_id": @26
               },
           @3: @{
                   @"subcategory": @"Facial Massage",
                   @"subcategory_id": @27
               }
           }
       };
```

---

```
NSLog(@"shop_name: %@", [tempDic objectForKey:@"shop_name"]);

NSDictionary *tempDict = [tempDic objectForKey:@"subcategory"];

NSArray *allKeys = [tempDict allKeys];

for (int i = 0; i < allKeys.count; i++)
{
    NSString *key = allKeys[i];

    NSDictionary *item = [tempDict objectForKey:key];

    NSLog(@"key:%@", key);

    NSLog(@"subcategory:%@", [item objectForKey:@"subcategory"]);

    NSLog(@"subcategory_id:%@", [item objectForKey:@"subcategory_id"]);

    NSLog(@"dictionary:%@", item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone facing this same problem

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   NSArray *key=[MAtches valueForKey:[connt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.Shop_Name.text=[key valueForKey:@"shop_name"];
     retrn cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the response :

```
- (void)handleResponse:(NSDictionary *)response
{


responseParsedDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (id key in response) {
        NSMutableDictionary *subDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [subDictionary setObject:[[response objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"shop_name"] forKey:@"shop_name"];
        NSDictionary *subcategory = (NSDictionary *)[[response objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"subcategory"];
        NSMutableDictionary *subCategoryArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (id subKey in subcategory) {
            NSMutableDictionary *subcategoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [subcategoryDictionary setObject:[[subcategory objectForKey:subKey] objectForKey:@"subcategory"]forKey:@"subcategory"];
            [subcategoryDictionary setObject:[[subcategory objectForKey:subKey] objectForKey:@"subcategory_id"]forKey:@"subcategory_id"];
            [subCategoryArray setObject:subcategoryDictionary forKey:subKey];
        }
        [subDictionary setObject:subCategoryArray forKey:@"subcategory"];

        [responseParsedDictionary setObject:subDictionary forKey:key];

    }
}`enter code here`

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.Shop_Name.text= [[responseParsedDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]] objectForKey:@"shop_name"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return responseParsedDictionary.count;
}
```